# Get View + ViewModel from Caliburn.Micro in unit tests

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, testing, silverlight-toolkit, caliburn.micro

We're using Caliburn.Micro to do all the magic of kickstarting our Silverlight app.

I'd like to have a play with testing an initialised view being hosted by the Silverlight Unit Testing Framework's TestPanel, but (without a deep dive) I don't know how to get at the view.

Does anyone know the magic to pull an initialised View + ViewModel out of Caliburn?

Comment: What exactly are you testing?  The purpose of MVVM is that you can unit test your view models in isolation of any view code.  In fact, ideally you should have very little to no code in your views (code behind files).

Comment: Oh, our tests are already from the view down, and while there's no real logic in the view, there's still plenty to test there - binding, visibility, enabling/disabling, etc. We're using SpecFlow to write acceptance tests, and it's working very nicely, but testing from the viewmodel down leads to a lot of bespoke steps. I wanted to see if I replicate something like capybara for driving the view - it would clean up our test implementations and validate what does live in the xaml.

Comment: Ok I'm slightly confused, it sounds interesting what you're doing, but how are you testing view bindings with SpecFlow?  Wouldn't a UI testing tool such as Project White be more suited for testing your views?

Comment: Ah. Somehow I hadn't really clicked that White was for Silverlight too. I was intending on indirectly testing the bindings by simply ensuring the displayed values or visibility, etc were what they should be according to the view model. 

White looks like it could be more like what I'm after - proper outside-in testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [white](http://white.codeplex.com/) for doing automated UI testing :)

Just as an aside, you can get an instance of your view that Caliburn.Micro attaches, by overriding the `OnViewLoaded` or `AttachView` method in your view model, which is part of the `Screen` type.